# echo the value of the specific buttons on the modal form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using a modal form which will show up a button if the buttons on the webpage will click. but my button is in `href` form, see my code below.

```
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" value="#01" name="btn" class="button2 btn btn-success" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" >form</a>
```

there are a lots of "Form Buttons" choices on my webpage,
QUESTION: how could I echo the value of the current "Form Button" which were clicked and show it up on the Modal Form? check my Echo code where I used inside my Modal Form:

```
<?php 
     if (isset($_POST["btn"]))
 {
    echo $_POST["btn"];
 }
?>
```

here is the modal code;

```
<!-- Modal header starts -->                                                
                        <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                              <div class="modal-dialog">
                                  <div class="modal-content">
                                      <div class="modal-header1" style="padding:10px 15px;">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" >&times;</button>
                                        <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> 求人応募</h4>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body" style="padding:10px 10px;">
    <!-- Modal header ends -->
    <!-- Modal Application form starts -->  
                     <div class="modal-body">
                            <form action="confirmation.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                            <?php 
                                   if (isset($_POST["btn"]))
                                   {
                                       echo $_POST["btn"];
                                   }
                            ?>
```

here is the different page after the modal form, click next and proceed to this page. to echo all the input details plus the botton id "#01"

```
<form id="main-contact-form1"  style="background-color: #f0f8ff; padding: 20px;" class="contact-form1" name="contact-form1" method="post" action="sendappli.php" role="form">   

                          <div class="label-field-pair">
                            <label>ID</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id='id' name='id' value='<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>'  />
                          </div>

                          <div class="label-field-pair">
                            <label>name</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id='name' name='name' value='<?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?>'  />
                          </div>
```

here is the button code inside the modal to proceed to next page

```
    <div class="modal-body">
                            <form action="confirmation.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

here is the code for my Modal together with the "NEXT" button to proceed to the 2nd page

```
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                              <div class="modal-dialog">
                                  <div class="modal-content">
                                      <div class="modal-header1" style="padding:10px 15px;">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" >&times;</button>
                                        <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> FORM</h4>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body" style="padding:10px 10px;">

                                        <h6 class="sub-heading-2 tiny text-medium text-center-xs">

                                        <?php
                                            $divName="btnval";
                                                echo "<div id=$divName></div>";
                                        ?>

                                        </h6>   
                                         <div class="modal-body">
                            <form action="confirmation.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        <!-- First Name Filed Starts -->
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name">NAME</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required="required" placeholder="Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <!-- First Name Filed Ends -->
```

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="NEXT">
```

and here is the 2nd page to echoing the information and button value "#01"

```
<form id="main-contact-form1"  style="background-color: #f0f8ff; padding: 20px;" class="contact-form1" name="contact-form1" method="post" action="sendappli.php" role="form">   

                          <div class="label-field-pair">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id='name' name='name' value='<?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?>'  />
                          </div>

                          <div class="label-field-pair">
                            <label>ID</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id='id' name='id' value='<?php echo $_GET["btnval"]; ?>'  />
                          </div>
```

[image]

Comment: You can take use of JavaScript or Jquery

Comment: You can't do this in this way without page reload.

Comment: hello @Chiru thank you for the quick response I used a script but it won't work either. <script>
  window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementsByName("btn").onclick = function(){
    document.getElementsByName("btn")[0].value = this.value;
    document.forms.myform.submit();
   }
  };
</script>

Comment: can you reedit my codes to work fine?

Comment: You have to through some script which repeatedly checks whether it is pressed or not.....

Comment: You want to say that you have 2 or more buttons in form, and different buttons do different actions?

Comment: It looks like you're using Bootstrap modal. See the events that come with that https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-events - you can access the opener link from the `event.relatedTarget` variable

Comment: I have a lot of buttons with one action. for example, 3 buttons will connect to 1 Modal form, but I like to echo the specific value which buttons were clicked?

Comment: yes @kyra I am using bootstrap modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    $(document).on("click", ".model_open", function () {
        var btnval = $(this).data('btnval'); 
       $(".modal-body #btnval").text( btnval );
    $('#hiddenid').val(btnval ); //Change this
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" value="#01" name="btn" class="button2 btn btn-success model_open" data-btnval = "#01" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" >form</a>
   
    <!-- Modal header starts -->                                                
                            <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                                      <div class="modal-content">
                                          <div class="modal-header1" style="padding:10px 15px;">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" >&times;</button>
                                            <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> 求人応募</h4>
                                    </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body" style="padding:10px 10px;">
<h6 class="sub-heading-2 tiny text-medium text-center-xs">
                                        <?php
                                                echo "<div id="btnval"></div>";
                                        ?>
                                        </h6>
        <!-- Modal header ends -->
        <!-- Modal Application form starts -->  
                         <div class="modal-body">

                                <form action="confirmation.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" id="hiddenid" name="btnval">
 <!-- First Name Filed Starts -->
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name">NAME</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required="required" placeholder="Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="NEXT">
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine in my Modal, but the value of the current button didn't echo on the Modal Form. :(

Comment: sure wait will send it here

Comment: hello @Nandhi Kumar stackoverflow not allowing me to post a long code here. can I send it to your email address?

Comment: only post your echo part of model. that is enough to check

Comment: Check alert(btnval);

Comment: I think it will helpful to find solutions

Comment: yes @Nandhi Kumar I am still working on the possible solutions, thank you for your help, it is really appreciated. hope soon will find out the right code for this ^__^

Comment: goog morning @Nandhi Kumar, wow! Your code is functioning perfectly. thank you for the effort to find the solution. high appreciated ^__^ God blessed

Comment: hello @Nandhi is it possible to put some NAME inside your code <div id="btnval"></div> --> like this <div id="btnval" name="id"></div>. to get the button value which echoed on the modal, to echo to another set of form too?

Comment: Use  btnval = ("#btnval").text(); to get he button value

Comment: See my updated answer. pls include $before getting the text value i.e
var btnval = $("#btnval").text();

Comment: from the form button (data-btnval = "#01") --> to Modal Form (div id="btnval" name="btnval") --> get the name and display <?php echo $_GET["btnval"]; ?>

Comment: :( I don't get it

Comment: I think wrong replacing of code that's why I got an error. but now the code is functioning well, and super thank you for that. but that's not what I am trying to show in my code :(. I just like to get the value of this echoed  <div id="btnval"> which is the "#01" and echo it also to another form <?php echo $_GET["btnval"]; ?>

Comment: i.e   
from the Webpage Button (data-btnval = "#01") --> to Modal Form (div id="btnval" name="btnval") --> get the "name" and display/echo to another Form2 <?php echo $_GET["btnval"]; ?>

Comment: You can use hidden text and append the "btnval" to the hidden field. Once the form submission get the value from the hidden field name

Comment: yes, the codes work good ^__^ thank you for your time this is really appreciated. but when I applied it to my codes it's not what I suppose to show out. :( sorry... sorry....

Comment: Which error you got? can you share the echo part of anothor model

Comment: I just like to put "name"  on this code <div id="btnval"></div> to use it in "echo" <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?> and displayed to onther set of form in different page. :( hope soon will find it how.

Comment: hello @Nandhi please have patience. look at the updated post. thank you

Comment: how will you load next model using java script or form action

Comment: the form Modal is in the webpage1 and connected to webpage2. after the Modal form was fill-outed and clicked next button, it will proceed to webpage2 to echo the inputted details on the form before will send to email address. all are good and functioning perfectly. all I have to insert the value of the button which was your given code. ^__^

Comment: I tried the updated code of yours. but it didn't echo the Button id to webpage2. is it possible to get the echoed button id in the modal and echo it to webpage2 using "get"?

Comment: I used this code to echo the value --> value='<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>' and I got this error --> <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: id in <b>C:\xampp\confirmation.php</b> on line <b>320</b><br />

Comment: hello @Nandhi good morning, I get the idea of your code ^_^. I just wondering now how could I transfer the input type box on the other page to function it, in the same effect. which is to echo the "#01" value?

Comment: good afternoon @Nandhi I don't have an idea how could I put a name value inside the <div id> to get the of its value and echoing it to another page. :(

Comment: Did you find the solution??

Comment: hello @Nandhi thank you for responding. I've used this code to put a name inside the din id --> <?php
            $divName="btnval";
             echo "<div id=$divName></div>";
           ?> but same error again it son't display the #01 :(

Comment: I don't have 2 modal, just only 1 modal I have. the process is; inside the first page, there is a button when it clicks it will pop-up the modal to show the form and the value of the current button. after fill-outed the form there is a "NEXT" button to proceed to the second page to echoing all of the information inserted in the form together with the "value #01" after the user checked the information there is a "SEND" button to send it to my email address.

Comment: please have patience. check the updated post. thank you so much ^^

Comment: hello @Nandhi I got error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'btnval' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ' --> on this code <?php
                                                echo "<div id="btnval"></div>";
                                        ?>

Comment: please check the photo I've posted ^^

Comment: hello, @Nandhi until now I can't solve my problem. :( have you see the picture I've posted?

Comment: hello, @Nandhi thank you for your help, my problem is now solved ^__^

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log(e.relatedTarget)
})
```

That method triggers when the modal is shown on screen, the `e.relatedTarget` contains the opener element, which can be accessed by jQuery as `$(e.relatedTarget)`

See Bootstrap modal events here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-events

Working example https://codepen.io/D-Heap/pen/VrLeXR

Comment: Although maybe correct, it be very nice to have more explanation than just the answer code. :) If someone else ever lands on this answer via Google or something, some more text might help them understand what's happening. ;)

Comment: thank you @kyra is this for script right, what about my echo code should I recode that?

Comment: @Jordumus - was just doing that :)

Comment: @MarvinAcosta - if your modal content is already on the page you have to `echo` the button info via Javascript. If the modal is populated via Ajax then you need to pass the info to the request to make it available to PHP.

Comment: @kyra my modal is also on the page. I tried your given code but it won't work either :(

Comment: @MarvinAcosta - my example only shows the opener element in the console, open your inspector and look at the logs

Comment: I also check the bootstrap modal link but there's no related explanation posted there. hope someone can help me out in my code.

Comment: hello @kyra it didn't echo :(

Comment: @MarvinAcosta - Either you show us the code you have or amend the code I sent you to fit your purpose.

Comment: @MarvinAcosta - If you look at the Pen above, you see I added `<div>Opener value is: <span id="opener"></span>` to the modal-body. And in the JS this line `$('#opener').html($(e.relatedTarget).attr('value'))` sets the content of the `span#opener`. You don't need the PHP block in your modal-body.

Comment: hello @Kyra good morning. the solution to my problem is answered by Nandhi Kumar already. thank you for your help also ^__^ Gob blessed you too ^___^

Comment: @MarvinAcosta - Then you should accept his answer :)